# multipoint regular expressions match with less for loops and less class re-initialization. optimization

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

Is there a way to do multiple regular expressions matches in vba without instantiating multiple instances of the regexp object? For example I want to do several points of regular expression matching between several different fields of data.

For illustrative purposes consider this.

```
 
column 1       column 2         column 3

AAATDD         Airplane         Transportation/Airplane
BBBTDD         Bus              Transportation/Bus
CCCFDD         Chocolate        Food/Chocolate
DDDFDD         Dog              Food/Potato
```

So as you can see the first letter in Column 1 is A, which matches the Description in Column 2 for Airplane which matches the type of Transportation (indicated by the T in Column 1 "AAATDD") in Column 3 for Airplane. All is well. But in Column 1 there is the peculiar entry for Dog which is listed as a Food and Potato.

Right now I have (pseudo) code like this:

```
for i = 1 to endpoint
    set regexp as new regexp
    regexp.pattern is myPattern
    set colmatches = regexp.execute()

    If Column1_Entry(i) = myMatch.value then
         pass test
    Else
         throw exception
    End if
 next i
```

but the problem is I can only check the regular expression given by my pattern. For example, my next few lines have to check the SAME values just looking out for a different thing.

When I'm ready to do the next set of matches to determine validity i.e. on Column 3 matching Transportation/"Airplane" to "Airplane" in Column 2 I need to unset regexp and reset myPattern. Is there anyway around this? or a way to maybe store the regularexpressions as a list or array? So they can be looped through in turn? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using an array of expressions and a loop seem like a viable approach. How many expressions do you have, and how much data to process?

Comment: an array of expressions? like an array of regexp patterns? that's interesting. any idea how that could be implemented? its actually not huge amounts of data. its maybe 600 entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim arr

arr = Array("pattern1","pattern2","pattern3")

set regexp as new regexp

for i = 1 to endpoint     
     for n = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
        regexp.pattern = arr(n)
        set colmatches = regexp.execute()      
        If Column1_Entry(i) = myMatch.value then          
           pass test     
        Else          
           throw exception     
        End if  
    next n
next i
```